# BSOD!! page_fault_in_nonpaged_area

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

my computer suddenly came up with this blue screen, it says it has page_fault_in_nonpaged_area
is there any fix in this error?please help.

Comment: Which Windows version are you using?

Comment: im using windows xp sir..

Comment: Maybe now is a good time to delete [your answer](http://i.imgur.com/eJ2hY.png) on a [similar issue](http://superuser.com/questions/185416/i-randomly-have-a-bsod-will-recovering-the-pc-make-it-work/185506#185506)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be anything from bad memory to a virus infection, see the link below. click 50: on the left side for more info

http://aumha.org/a/stop.htm

0x00000050: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Requested data was not in memory. An invalid system memory address was referenced. Defective memory (including main memory, L2 RAM cache, video RAM) or incompatible software (including remote control and antivirus software) might cause this Stop message, as may other hardware problems (e.g., incorrect SCSI termination or a flawed PCI card).

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd recommend is to remove any recently installed hardware. This can occasionally be caused by a driver writing to protected memory.

The second thing I'd recommend would be to run [Memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) and see if you have a bad stick of RAM.

Comment: i dont remember any software that i installed on or before that error happened..

Comment: Adding to satanicpuppy's answer: try booting to Safe Mode first. If Windows boots up fine there, then it's possible one of the drivers might be causing the issue.

Comment: its not going to safe mode either, its like selecting safe mode and nothing happens, it just reboots and i will select again the safe mode..all over again..

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your drivers are up to date as well as BIOS, you can check the manufacture page for these. Also, if you can run a ram test with MemTest86+ you might find you have a bad stick. Also check for overheating, blow out the PC (outdoors) and see if that was the issue.

You could also user [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) to see if that might give you more info, when the system BSOD's it writes out a file and this app is one of the easier ways you can find what file cause the issue. Some people can also take the dumps and help you debug them, try uploading it here if it is small and I could take a look at it or maybe someone else would chime in.