# I randomly have a BSOD, will recovering the PC make it work?

Tags: windows-xp, bsod

I randomly have the Blue Screen of Death, it happens to me a lot.

Do you think recovering the PC will make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Set the machine to do mini dumps rather than full memory dumps, then use this utility to read the details about what drivers were loaded at the time next time you start up.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html

Answer (score 0):

Possibly.

It depends on what's actually causing the problem. If it's bad software or drivers then it should. However, if it's down to bad memory modules (say) then it won't. You need to find out what the BSOD actually is - see the answers to [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/42386/pc-blue-screens-and-then-instantly-reboots-how-do-i-stop-this-or-find-the-error) which will tell you how to get at the error. Then search Google for the error and see what solutions are offered.

Ultimately you might need to do a full re-install of the OS to cure the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep getting different BSOD messages, it is more likely a hardware problem.  First thing to check is the RAM using something like Memtest.  You can also try running some other hardware diagnostic.

Comment: Good point, if you can reproduce it by running program X and then the system always crashes, it's most likely a software fault. If it happens randomly and as noted you are getting different messages it is more likely to be a hardware fault.